# Python: print binary as string

Tags: python

I have a crawler that parses the HMTL of a given site and prints parts of the source code. Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
import re

class Crawler:

    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    keyword = 'arroz'

    def extra(self):
        url = "http://buscando.extra.com.br/search?w=" + self.keyword
        r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)    
        print(r.url)
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url, None, self.headers)).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        return soup.encode('utf-8')

    def __init__(self):
        extra = self.extra()
        print(extra)

Crawler()
```

My code works fine, but it prints the source with an annoying `b'` before the value. I already tried to use `decode('utf-8')` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

If I don't use the `encode('utf-8')` I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 25, in <module>
    Crawler()
  File "crawler.py", line 23, in __init__
    print(extra)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2030' in position
13345: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: So why are you using `encode` here? Try just `return soup`.

Comment: Without this it returns the following error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 25, in <module>
    Crawler()
  File "crawler.py", line 23, in __init__
    print(extra)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2030' in position
13345: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: `bytes` doesn't have an `encode` method in Python 3 so you are starting with a string and converting it to a byte string

Comment: @chucksmash Using `encode('utf-8')` I've stoped the error above. But I've created a new one: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2030' in position 13345: character maps to <undefined>`.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code as given except replacing `return soup.encode('utf-8')` with `return soup`, it works fine. My environment:

- OS: Ubuntu `15.10`
- Python: `3.4.3`
- python3 dist-packages bs4 version: `beautifulsoup4==4.3.2`

This leads me to suspect that the problem lies with your environment, not your code. Your stack trace mentions `cp850.py` and your source is hitting a `.com.br` site - this makes me think that perhaps the default encoding of your shell can't handle unicode characters. Here's the Wikipedia page for [cp850 - Code Page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).

You can check the default encoding your terminal is using with:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
```

My terminal responds with:

```
'UTF-8'
```

I'm assuming yours won't and that this is the root of the issue you are running into.

**EDIT**:

In fact, I can exactly replicate your error with:

```
>>> print("\u2030".encode("cp850"))
```

So that's the issue - because of your computer's locale settings, `print` is implicitly converting to your system's default encoding and raising the UnicodeDecodeError.

Updating Windows to display unicode characters from the command prompt is a bit outside my wheelhouse so I can't offer any advice other than to direct you to a [relevant question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500).

Comment: Yeah! It returned `cp850`. What should I do?

Comment: I've tried the link solution, without success... thanks tho.